# The DIV won't fit everything inside it

Tags: html, css

I have the following div that renders wrongly:

[image]

The HTML is the one below:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"> 
  <img src="res/img/Logo.png" id="logo" />
  just regular content
  <ul class="mini-gallery">
    <a href="#"><li><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/17.jpg"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/10.jpg"></li></a>
    <a href="#"><li><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/3.jpg"></li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #E6B5E9;
  width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

ul.mini-gallery {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; 
}
ul.mini-gallery li
{   
  list-syle: none;
}
ul.mini-gallery img
{
  width: 310px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right:10px;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  border: none;
}
```

As you might have understood, the images should be within the div, not outside it. So why happens this and how can I solve it?

Comment: can you post the rest of your css? my suspicion is that you may be floating elements and not clearing them

Comment: There's not enough CSS here because I think the problem is with your `ul` or your `li` elements, not with the wrapper. I think you're floating some elements and they're rendered outside the `div`, even if they're inside. If this is the case, you can replace the `float` property with `display:inline-block`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tHp4j/

Comment: Also, your syntax is wrong. It's `<li><a>...`, not `<a><li>...`

Comment: use display inline-block on the div and display block on the divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, `overflow:auto` or a clearfix (what I've done below) will do it. I've also adjusted your HTML so that your anchors are children of your list elements and not the other way around:

```
<div class="content-wrapper"> 
    <img src="res/img/Logo.png" id="logo" />
    just regular content
    <ul class="mini-gallery">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/17.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/10.jpg" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="res/img/gallery/bucuresti/3.jpg" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2uMDK/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is floating elements without clearing them. You can use a clearfix or just set `overflow: hidden` on `.content-wrapper`

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pMYT7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Because you float the images. To allow the container `.content-wrapper` div to contain them again, add `overflow:auto;` to it.

```
.content-wrapper {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #E6B5E9;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```